# How do I show bicycle lanes using google maps SDK on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Google Maps has an option to show bicycle lanes. I'm unable to find the way to enable showing that on Google Map's Android SDK. I also looked into Map styling options and couldn't find the option there.

This picture shows Google Maps with the bicycle layer enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of writing, `Bicycle layers` are not yet available for Google Maps Platform - **Maps SDK for Android**. If you would like this feature to be implemented, I suggest that you file a feature request on the Google Issue tracker in this [component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188870&template=788012).

Here's a similar feature request filed under the *Maps SDK for iOS* component: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822615

> UPDATE: There is now an entry in the Google Issue Tracker which you
>   could star to receive updates and to increase the issue's priority.
>   You can view and star the issue here:
>   https://issuetracker.google.com/141610958

Comment: thanks for your response and this info. A question - has an issue for this this feature request not been filed for SDK for Android yet? I tried searching for one but couldn't find it.

Comment: There's no entry yet by the time I answered this post. But it seems like someone just filed one recently - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141610958

Comment: Yeah, thats me; I filed that. Hoping that Maps team will consider and do it sometime soon.